# How can i fix this erros from Xcode, building a iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, android-studio, flutter

I don't know why this happens for the 2nd time... 
This code is from Xcode.

I already try to uninstall and install Xcode.

There is here a screenshot of my pubspec.yaml maybe can help. 
[enter image description here][1]

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/fabionevez/Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+12/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:356:62: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      userData[@"lastSignInTimestamp"] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:lastSignInDate];
                                         ~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/fabionevez/Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:764:16: warning: 'timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          settings.timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = (bool)call.arguments[@"timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled"];
                   ^
    In file included from /Users/fabionevez/Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.11/ios/Classes/CloudFirestorePlugin.m:8:
    In file included from /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:49:
    In file included from /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.h:25:
    /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/FirebaseFirestore/FIRFirestoreSettings.h:69:20: note: 'timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
        __attribute__((deprecated));
                       ^
    1 warning generated.
    duplicate symbol '_GDTCCTNeedsNetworkConnectionInfo' in:
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport/libGoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.a(GDTCOREvent+NetworkConnectionInfo 2.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._observers' in:
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FBLPromise._error' in:
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/libPromisesObjC.a(FBLPromise 2.o)
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore/libFirebaseFirestore.a(FIRTransaction.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRTransaction._firestore' in:
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore/libFirebaseFirestore.a(FIRTransaction 2.o)
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore/libFirebaseFirestore.a(FIRTransaction.o)
    duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_FIRWriteBatch._dataConverter' in:
        /Users/fabionevez/Desktop/app/loja_roupa/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore/libFirebaseFirestore.a(FIRWriteBatch 2.o)

    ld: 44 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
´´´


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx1dg.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to upgrade the firebase package and run **flutter clean** command